# Converting one list into individual ones

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
list = ['t' , 'r', 'q', ']', '[' , 'd', 'e', 'n', ']' , '[', 'l', 't']
```

How can I convert create individual lists, like:

```
list1 = ['t', 'r', 'q']
list2 = ['d' , 'e', 'n']
list3 = ['l', 't']
```

Comment: You really have `']'` and `'['` strings in your list? How did those get there? Did you call `str()` on a list object at some point?

Comment: @Martijn how the enclosing `[]`s isn't also a string is interesting... That wouldn't be the result of a `str`

Comment: @JonClements: Exactly. There is context missing here; most likely this is the end of a long chain of [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would also suggest not using `list` as a variable name, as that shadows the [built-in `list`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list)

Comment: Dear Anbar, please specify where you get this data from, how it ended up in this format and what you are ultimately intending to do. I concur with @MartijnPieters that this looks like a X-Y-Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [itertools groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

l = ['t' , 'r', 'q', ']', '[' , 'd', 'e', 'n', ']' , '[', 'l', 't']
new_l = [list(group) for i, group in itertools.groupby(l,
    lambda x: x in [']', '[']) if not i]
# [['t', 'r', 'q'], ['d', 'e', 'n'], ['l', 't']]
```

You could do it also without lambda (credit goes to [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements)):

```
new_l = [list(group) for i, group in itertools.groupby(l,
    set('[]').intersection) if not i]
```

Comment: This would be my preferred way of doing it. Note that creating a tuple is not needed as you can use `lambda x: x in '[]'` instead... Or, because of the `if not i`, you can avoid a lambda and use `set('[]').intersection` to group the non `[]`'s

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I understand your comment. Please feel free to edit my answer or suggest a new one (which one you find more appropriate)

Comment: Got it in the meantime.

Comment: Same idea as @JonClements `']['.count` might be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @ddelemeny I wish I'd thought of it - I'll admit using `str.count` never crossed my mind and I definitely prefer it to the `set.intersection` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to have leading & trailing brackets, I would join them into a string then split them:

```
joinedList = "".join(list)
splitList = joinedList.split('][')
```

From your code (and as pointed out in the comments), `list` looks a bit strange and might have been a complete string before. You might want to process variables that gave you `list` instead.

Comment: To get the OPs desired output, you need an additional step to put the items back into characters, eg: `splitList = [list(el) for el in joinedList.split('][')]`

Comment: True, but I think that's probably being too pedantic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
temp=[]
final=[]
for item in list:
    if item != ']':
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        final.append(temp)
        temp=[]
```

I guess the only advantage here is that items don't have to be strings.

But as it has been pointed out in the comments, you should probably avoid having this kind of a list in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other posters that it seems like you've ended up with weird looking input.

If your input is *really* for sure formatted like you say, and you're sure that you won't have malformed input, you can do what you want like so:

```
input = ['t' , 'r', 'q', ']', '[' , 'd', 'e', 'n', ']' , '[', 'l', 't']
scratch = list(input)
output = []

def find_bracket(L):
    try:
        return L.index(']')
    except:
        return -1

bracket_index = find_bracket(scratch)
while bracket_index > 0:
    output.append( scratch[:bracket_index] )
    scratch = scratch[bracket_index+2:]
    bracket_index = find_bracket(scratch)
output.append( scratch )

print output
```

Gives me:

```
[['t', 'r', 'q'], ['d', 'e', 'n'], ['l', 't']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
>>> li = ['t' , 'r', 'q', ']', '[' , 'd', 'e', 'n', ']' , '[', 'l', 't']
>>> list1, list2, list3 =  [[c for c in a] for a in "".join(li).split("][")]
#OUTPUT
>>> list1
['t', 'r', 'q']
>>> list2
['d', 'e', 'n']
>>> list3
['l', 't']
```