# Altering characters in strings

Tags: python, list

```
code =   ['#+/084&"', '#3*#%#+', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.#7&33&', '#*#71%', '']
```

How can I alter this list so that if I ,for example, want to change all of the '#' for 'D', the list will appear as such:

```
code =   ['D+/084&"', 'D3*D%D+', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.D7&33&', 'D*D71%', '']
```

Comment: In the meantime, your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309731/converting-one-list-into-individual-ones) has still several question marks hanging over it in the comments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also map the replace operation to the list:

```
map(lambda x: str.replace(x, '#', 'D'), code)
```

If it is in Python 3 you might need:

```
list(map(lambda x: str.replace(x, '#', 'D'), code))
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `str.replace()` on each value in a list comprehension:

```
code = [s.replace('#', 'D') for s in code]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> code = ['#+/084&"', '#3*#%#+', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.#7&33&', '#*#71%', '']
>>> code[:] = [x.replace("#", "D") for x in code]
>>> code
['D+/084&"', 'D3*D%D+', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.D7&33&', 'D*D71%', '']
>>>
```

*Note:* `[:]` is only needed if you want the list object to remain the same.  Otherwise, you can remove it.